# Не получается вставить контакт

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь вставить контакт, но никаких результатов не получаю. Ошибок тоже никаких, в чем может быть причина?

```
    Account account = Utils.getInstance(this).getAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
    Log.d("logba", "addContact : rawContactInsertIndex=" + rawContactInsertIndex);
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
            .build());

    try {
        Log.d("logba", "addContact : before results");
        ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
        Log.d("logba", "addContact : after results");
        for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
            Log.d("logba", "addContact : result=" + result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("logba", "addContact : e=" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Я уж подумал, речь зайдёт о проводах и разъёмах. :)

Comment: А в логах-то что? Если ничего, то уровень логирования поменяйте на debug.

Comment: интересно как бы тогда объяснил что не получается вставить в разъём :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл причину, в первом блоке .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex) был лишним. Вместо

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
        .build());
```

надо вставить

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account != null ? account.type : null)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account != null ? account.name : null)
            .build());
```